# display multiple images in one directory using imshow python

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to display multiple images in one directory.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
import math

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline

dir_path = 'img'
images = os.listdir(dir_path)
img_paths = [os.path.join(dir_path, i) for i in images]
img_paths.sort()
img_all = np.array([cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(p), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) for p in img_paths])


def display_helper(images, cmap=None):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=20, ncols=2, figsize=(15,6))
    for a in ax:
        a.imshow(img, interpolation='none')

display_helper(img_all)
```

But I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'imshow'
```

How can I display multiple images by using imshow ?

Thanks!

Comment: you need `plt.imshow()` or in long version `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`

Comment: I rolled back the edit, because it made the problem more obscure. Now, as you have it, there are two problems (1) `ax` is 2D, so to loop over all axes use `for a in ax.flat:` (2) You forgot to specify in your loop how `img` relates to `images`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=20, ncols=2, figsize=(15,6))
```

that gives `ax` as an `np.array` of shape `(20,2)`. So when you do `for a in ax`, `a` is an `np.array` of `2` axes. To fix it, change the following line to:

```
for a in ax.flatten():
```